# Why the onPress button doesn't send me to my current location?

Tags: react-native, expo

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the position button in the map, to go to the user current location. For the location I'm using `import * as Location from 'expo-location';`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { LocationView, LocationBtn } from '../components/styles';

function Map(props) {
  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setMapRegion({
        longitude: location.coords.longitude,
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      });
      console.log('location', location);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={props.mapType}
        // showsUserLocation={true}
        loadingEnabled
        initialRegion={mapRegion}
        userInterfaceStyle="light"
        showsTraffic
      >
        <Marker coordinate={mapRegion}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/marker.png')} style={{ height: 90, width: 90 }} />
        </Marker>
      </MapView>
      <LocationView>
        <LocationBtn onPress={() => mapRegion}>
          <MaterialIcons name="my-location" size={30} color="black" style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 13 }} />
        </LocationBtn>
      </LocationView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    height: '100%',
  },
});

export default Map;
```

By far I have put `mapRegion` state which it have the current location.
When I press the button, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by going to the user location? Looking at your code, you're saving your coordinates to the `mapRegion` state.

The `onPress` prop of `LocationBtn` has `() => mapRegion` which does nothing. It's just a function that has `mapRegion` return value.

Comment: I know that, I'm trying to make the screen center to my current location. I do get longitude and latitude but I'm not understanding how to use them to center the screen to those coordinates.

Comment: Can you try adding `region` prop in `MapView` as stated in the `react-native-maps` doc.
`<MapView ... region={mapRegion} >`